# Two time picker Dialogs with starting time and ending time

Tags: android, android-timepicker

I have two separate time pickers in Edit text for starting time and ending time. When I select starting time as 9:00:am after I selecting ending time it is not lesser than starting time. Ending time should be greater than starting time. Suggest some solutions.

```
int hour=0;
int minute=0;
TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;

start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(Jobcompletion.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hourOfDay, int selectedMinute) {


                    String AM_PM = " AM";
                    String mm_precede = "";
                    String hh_precede = "";

                        if (hourOfDay >= 12) {
                            AM_PM = " PM";
                            if (hourOfDay >= 13 && hourOfDay < 24) {
                                hourOfDay -= 12;
                            } else {
                                hourOfDay = 12;
                            }
                        } else if (hourOfDay == 0) {
                            hourOfDay = 12;
                        }
                        if (hourOfDay < 10) {
                            hh_precede = "0";
                        }
                        if (selectedMinute < 10) {
                            mm_precede = "0";
                        }


                        start.setText(hh_precede+hourOfDay + ":" +mm_precede + selectedMinute+ " " + AM_PM);
                    }



            }, hour, minute, false);    //12hour=false/true
            mTimePicker.setTitle("Select StartTime");
            mTimePicker.show();

        }
    });
    end.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      /*  Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);*/
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(Jobcompletion.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hourOfDay, int selectedMinute ) {


                    String AM_PM = " AM";
                    String mm_precede = "";
                    String hh_precede = "";


                        if (hourOfDay >= 12) {
                            AM_PM = " PM";
                            if (hourOfDay >= 13 && hourOfDay < 24) {
                                hourOfDay -= 12;
                            } else {
                                hourOfDay = 12;
                            }
                        } else if (hourOfDay == 0) {
                            hourOfDay = 12;
                        }

                        if (hourOfDay < 10) {
                            hh_precede = "0";
                        }
                        if (selectedMinute < 10) {
                            mm_precede = "0";
                        }

                        end.setText(hh_precede + hourOfDay + ":" + mm_precede + selectedMinute + " " + AM_PM);

                }
            }, hour, minute, false);
               Log.e("Min",String.valueOf(minute));
            mTimePicker.setTitle("Select EndTime");
            mTimePicker.show();


        }
    });
```

Comment: no one help for some valuable questions

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if you are doing *any* date/time manipulation in your app, I highly recommend importing the [Java 310 Backport for Android (ThreeTenABP)](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP):

```
compile 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.0.3'
```

As the `Date` and `Calendar` classes provided by Java 7 are a mess.

---

You need to implement the validation yourself. A simple implementation would be to keep values of the start and end times, then check if one is greater than the other. This code assumes use of the 310 backport:

```
private LocalTime mStartTime;
private LocalTime mEndTime;

@Override
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker picker, int hourOfDay, int minuteOfHour) {
    mStartTime = LocalTime.of(hourOfDay, minuteOfHour);

    if(mStartTime.isAfter(mEndTime)) {
        // Handle case
    }
}
```

Lastly, there is no reason you should be setting date/time text yourself. Android provides a [`DateUtils`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html) class for this purpose:

```
long start = ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDate.now(), mStartTime, ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant().toEpochMilli();

String startTime = DateUtils.formatDateTime(this, start, DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME);
```

This will take into account the users settings (12 hour/24 hour), and the locale of the device.

---

Here is the same code using the Java 7 classes:

```
private Date mStartTime;
private Date mEndTime;

@Override
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker picker, int hourOfDay, int minuteOfHour) {
    Calendar date = new GregorianCalendar();
    date.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
    date.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minuteOfHour);
    mStartTime = date.getTime();

    if(mStartTime.after(mEndTime)) {
        // Handle case
    }
}

String startTime = DateUtils.formatDateTime(this, mStartTime.getTime(), DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME);
```

Comment: Good answer, except that suggestion of using Joda-Time as an alternative to java.time. The second sentence on the [Joda-Time web site](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) advises migration to java.tim. The Joda-Time project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), actively maintained but no new feature work. Both Joda-Time and java.time are led by the same man, Stephen Colbourne. Also, ThreeTenABP fits better than Joda-Time given Android’s 65K limit of number of methods.